# jquery mobile align options box with text input field

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have been trying to get an options box to align horizontally with text input fields. I have put it in a grid to try and make it work but it wont align correctly. here is my code:

```
<form id="frmNewReservation">
                <div class="ui-grid-c">
                    <div class='ui-block-a' >
                        <div class='ui-body ui-body-a' style='border:0px;'> 
                            <div class="ui-field-contain">
                                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                                    <div style="margin-top: 6px;">

                                    <select name="sortBy" id="sortBy"  data-mini="true" >
                                        <option value="#">All</option>
                                        <option value="#">Physical Size</option>
                                        <option value="#">Sizecode</option>
                                    </select>
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>


                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='ui-block-b'>
                            <div class='ui-body ui-body-a' style='border:0px;'>
                                <input type="text" name="textinput-5" id="textinput-5" placeholder="Text input" value="" data-mini="true">          
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                        <div class='ui-block-c'>
                            <div class='ui-body ui-body-a' style='border:0px;'>
                                <input type="text" name="textinput-5" id="textinput-5" placeholder="Text input" value="" data-mini="true">          
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                        <div class='ui-block-d'>
                            <div class='ui-body ui-body-a' style='border:0px;'>
                                <input type="text" name="textinput-5" id="textinput-5" placeholder="Text input" value="" data-mini="true">          
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                </div><!-- close grid -->

            </form>
```

JS fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/FGW2L/

Any ideas how I can fix this? Thanks

Comment: I would start with cleaning up your styles... there is a lot of inline CSS going on that should be in a <style></style> or in an external CSS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust the following styles on these elements.

```
div.ui-body { height: 41px; }
div.ui-field-contain { margin: 0px; }
```

*this would be easier to manage with a stylesheet rather than inline styles for everything (less repetitive too)

Comment: thats great works perfectly! The inline css is just for testing purposes... Thanks